# Odoo set default domain on uom in view of sale.order.line

Tags: odoo, view, odoo-9

I have been trying to set the default domain on the product_uom field in sale.order.line.  When you edit an existing quotation, it does not show units of measure in the same category as the default unit of sale.  So, if you sell in Units, you'd want to see Units and dozens.  Instead you see cm, g, in, etc.  When you create an order, you don't have this problem because these values are set through onchange.

I thought this was going to be really simple, but I can't for the life of me understand why my attempts are failing.  I've tried:

```
     <record id="sale_order_form_view_inherit_product_uomconv" model="ir.ui.view">

        <field name="name">sale.order.form.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[@name='product_uom']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="domain">[('category_id', '=', product_id.uom_id.category_id.id)]</attribute>
            </xpath>
            </field>
     </record>
```

I've also tried

```
      <record id="sale_order_form_view_inherit_product_uomconv" model="ir.ui.view">

        <field name="name">sale.order.form.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[@name='product_uom']" position="replace">
                <field name="product_uom" domain="[('category_id', '=', product_id.uom_id.category_id.id)]" attrs="{'readonly': [('state', 'in', ('sale','done', 'cancel'))]}" context="{'company_id': parent.company_id}" groups="product.group_uom" options='{"no_open": True}'/>
            </xpath>
            </field>
      </record>
```

I get the error "Uncaught Error: AttributeError: object has no attribute 'uom_id' ".  I don't really understand how this could be true.  The field product_id has been declared in the view, the database maps it to product.product, and the field is definitely not empty when I go to edit the quote.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check here the onchange [`product_id_change`](https://github.com/OCA/OCB/blob/9.0/addons/sale/sale.py#L743) that sets a domain for `product_uom`.

The best thing to do is override it in your module.

Such domain in a view is really error prone, because when you access nested objects as you do with `product_id.uom_id.category_id.id` you don't really know if all the values to satisfy this chain are there. Worse, odoo's view rendering is not smart enough to be "soft" in these conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  

There is already an onchange function that does this, but if you go back in and edit the form, nothing is changed... so onchange won't set the correct domain.  

I had another question from today that was similar, but it dealt with dynamic views. This is just a default view, and  I thought there would certainly be a way to do this.  I suppose I could inherit the model of sale.order.line and make a related field. Then I can make it invisible in the xml, and use that in the domain expression.. but it seems like it shouldn't have to come to that.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand why my original scenario failed... but I found a workaround.

```
class NewSaleOrderLine(models.Model):
_inherit = 'sale.order.line'
#These computed fields are for calculating the domain on a form edit
relcatid = fields.Many2one(related='product_uom.category_id',store=True)
```

now in the xml...

```
<record id="sale_order_form_view_inherit_product_uomconv" model="ir.ui.view">
   <field name="name">sale.order.form.inherit</field>
   <field name="model">sale.order</field>
   <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
   <field name="arch" type="xml">
       <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[@name='qty_to_invoice']" position="after">
           <field name="relcatid" invisible="1"/>
       </xpath>

       <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[@name='product_uom']" position="replace">
           <field name="product_uom" domain="[('category_id', '=', relcatid)]" attrs="{'readonly': [('state', 'in', ('sale','done', 'cancel'))]}" context="{'company_id': parent.company_id}" groups="product.group_uom" options='{"no_open": True}'/>
       </xpath>
   </field>
</record>
```

I'm still uncertain as to why this was necessary.

Comment: I'm thinking about this, and the only thing I didn't test was trying to change the domain before the product was selected... 

When I was debugging this, I did make a new line and select a product.  The domain was overwritten due to the default onchange function.  If I had went to change the uom before selecting a product, I don't know if it will be behave. In that case, relcatid would return False.  I'm thinking it should handle that ok, but I'll test tonight.

Comment: Actually, I think I found another bug.  Adding another product changes the domains of all the lines, and sets the uom category for the new line as the domain for ALL lines.  At first I thought I may have done something wrong overriding the view, but I removed it and upgraded the module... and it still does it.  I think there might be something wrong with the view handler.

Comment: As it turns out, my code works pretty well even when relcatid = False.  It works so well that I can just completely take out the domain changes in the onchange function, and everything works as it should.  

I'm definitely leaning towards a bug here though.